# ¿Cómo acceder a un atributo entre clases?

Tags: c++, poo, clase

Buenas, tengo el problema que quiero que las clases ''LuchadorBueno'' ''Luchador Malo'' accedan a su atributo ''Ki'' para poder modificarlo. Ambas clases estan moduladas en archivos .hpp . Ya lo intente haciendo clases amigas pero entonces solo una se logra quitar vida y la otra no, quisiera saber cual es el error.

```
//Luchador Malo
class LuchadorMalo{
 int posx;
 int posy;
 public:
     int vida;
     bool ganador;
     friend class LuchadorBueno;
     LuchadorMalo()
     {
     vida = 40;
     posx=13;
     posy=14;
     ganador=false;
     }
     bool go(){
     int dados=(1+rand()%2);
     if(dados==1){
     cout<<"Kannon ha dado una PATADA a Master Blaze"<<endl;
     cout<<"KI: ";
     }
     if(dados==2){
     cout<<"Kannon ha dado un GOLPE DURO a Master Blaze"<<endl;
     cout<<"KI: ";
     }

   }

    void posi(){
    int x=1+rand()%13;
    int y=1+rand()%13;
    posx=x;
    posy=y;
}
    int getposx(){
    return posx;
    }
    int getposy(){
    return posy;
    }

};

//Luchador Bueno
class LuchadorBueno{
 int posx;
 int posy;
 friend class LuchadorMalo;
  public:
        LuchadorMalo B;
     LuchadorBueno(){
     ki = 30;
     posx=1;
     posy=1;
     ganador=false;
     }
     int ki;
     bool ganador;
         bool go(){
                int dados=(1+rand()%2);
                if(dados==1){
                cout<<"Master Blaze ha dado una PATADA a Kannoni"<<endl;
                B.vida = B.vida-9;
                 cout<<"KI: "<<B.vida<<endl;

    }
    if(dados==2){
             cout<<"Mater Blaze ha dado un GOLPE DURO a Kannon"<<endl;
            B.vida = B.vida-4;
             cout<<"KI: "<<B.vida<<endl;
                }
    }
    void posi(){
                int x=1+rand()%13;
                int y=1+rand()%13;
                posx=x;
                posy=y;
               }

    int getposx(){
    return posx;
    }
    int getposy(){
    return posy;
    }
};
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?Alguna captura?

Comment: LuchadorBueno tiene ki pero no vida. LuchadorMalo tiene vida pero no ki. ¿Es correcto o debieran ambos tener ambos atributos?

Answer (score 0):

En base al principio de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29) sería mejor que los datos de un Luchador (vida, coordenadas, etc) fuesen privados.

Aunque preguntas como hacer que otra clase acceda al atributo lo mejor es justo lo contrario, prohibir que otra clase acceda a ese u otros atributos. En vez de eso crea uno o varios métodos públicos que se encarguen del comportamiento apropiado. Yo he creado un método `quitarVida` al que puede llamar cualquiera para reducir los puntos de vida de un Luchador, da igual que sea bueno o malo.

Finalmente, tienes código repetido, concretamente el método `posi` que es el mismo en ambas clases. Yo crearía una clase `Luchador` con los aspectos comunes a ambas clases y luego cada luchador heredaría de esta y añadiría sus particularidades.

Por ejemplo :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class Luchador
{
public:
    Luchador()
    {
        vida = 0;
        posx = 0;
        posy = 0;
        ki = 0;
        ganador = false;
    };
    Luchador( int vida, int ki, int posx, int posy )
    {
        this->vida = vida;
        this->ki = ki;
        this->posx = posx;
        this->posy = posy;
    };


    void posi() {
        int x = 1 + rand() % 13;
        int y = 1 + rand() % 13;
        posx = x;
        posy = y;
    };

    void quitarVida(int danyo)
    {
        vida -= danyo;
    };   

    int getVida()
    {
        return vida;
    };

    int getposx() {
        return posx;
    };

    int getposy() {
        return posy;
    };

private:
    int posx;
    int posy;
    int vida;
    int ki;
    bool ganador;
};

//Luchador Malo

class LuchadorMalo : public Luchador {
public:
    LuchadorMalo():Luchador(40, 0, 13, 14) {};

    bool go(Luchador& enemigo) {
        int dados = (1 + rand() % 2);
        if (dados == 1) {
            enemigo.quitarVida(9);
            cout << "Kannon ha dado una PATADA a Master Blaze" << endl;
            cout << "Vida: " << enemigo.getVida() << endl;
        }
        if (dados == 2) {
            enemigo.quitarVida(4);
            cout << "Kannon ha dado un GOLPE DURO a Master Blaze" << endl;
            cout << "Vida: " << enemigo.getVida() << endl;
        }

    }
};

//Luchador Bueno

class LuchadorBueno : public Luchador{
public:
    LuchadorBueno(): Luchador( 40, 30, 1, 1) { };

    bool go(Luchador& enemigo) {
        int dados = (1 + rand() % 2);
        if (dados == 1) {
            cout << "Master Blaze ha dado una PATADA a Kannoni" << endl;
            enemigo.quitarVida(9);
            cout << "Vida: " << enemigo.getVida() << endl;

        }
        if (dados == 2) {
            cout << "Mater Blaze ha dado un GOLPE DURO a Kannon" << endl;
            enemigo.quitarVida(4);
            cout << "Vida: " << enemigo.getVida() << endl;
        }
    }

};

int main() {
    LuchadorBueno bueno;
    LuchadorMalo malo;

    bueno.go( malo );
    malo.go( bueno );

    return 0;
}
```